# What is use of "Fill" property in System.Windows.Shapes.Line?

Tags: wpf, line, shapes, fill

What is use of `Fill` property in `System.Windows.Shapes.Line` in WPF?

```
<Line Fill="Red" Stroke="Black" X2="1"/>
```

Comment: It seems useless in Line, in fact it's just an inherited member from `Shape`. Normally we use `Stroke`. There are some cases in which the inherited members are meaningless in the derived class, using those members does not have any effect. I may wonder why it's there as a member of Line but in fact it's of the base class `Shape`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `King King` comment, answer is:

It seems useless in Line, in fact it's just an inherited member from `Shape`. Normally we use `Stroke`. There are some cases in which the inherited members are meaningless in the derived class, using those members does not have any effect. I may wonder why it's there as a member of Line but in fact it's of the base class `Shape`.